# VLC media player only plays Halfscreen instead of full

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, video, vlc

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my Windows 10 laptop.

This is something I need help with, when I open up a video in VLC and it plays, but it does not fit the width of the window, but remains half screen? Here are the screenshots of the problem :-

When not in full screen:

[image: When not in full screen]

When in full screen:

[image: When in full screen]

As you can see, that the pictures are not the screenshots; because when i took the screenshots, i couldn't get the picture of the video, it only gave took the picture of the vlc's blank screen. So, I took the picture using my phone.

Also, I would like to mention that Totem and mpv media players are working just fine but i don't know the problem with vlc.

I am using Lenovo Yoga 500.

Please help as soon as possible. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Is the white/grey background behind the text and the picture of the hand, the whole picture or is the blue color in full screen mode? Do you have `Intergrade video in interface` on, and `Resize interface to video size` off, in Tools-Settings?

Comment: Yes. But it still doesn't work.

Comment: Then I don't know, at least worth a try to remove VLC and reinstall it.

Comment: Ok. I'll try that. Anyways, thanks for replying. :)